# Is it bad to have threads waiting in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that basically contains

```
while(true) {
  current = BlockingQueue.take();
  results = queryDatabaseWith(current);
  AtomicReference.set( results );
}
```

Realistically the queue is only ever going to have a few things put on it, but it's important that when things are, the DB queries happen in the correct order. The atomic ref is fine as I only care about the results from the last DB query.

Is it bad practice to have this on a thread, basically waiting all day?

Comment: **NO**. Having waiting threads is exactly what you should do. Having waiting threads is (almost) free. Having _spinning_ threads isn't. WebServers like Tomcat can have literally hundreds of waiting threads.

Comment: One thread doing this, no, ten thousand thread doing this is a bad idea. As a very rough guide, each thread which runs rarely has an overhead of about 0.05% of 1 CPU.

Comment: Great. There's only going to be a handful of these threads on different queues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Waiting is the purpose for which threads originally were invented.  Threads have been around since long before most computers had more than one processor.  Multi-threading was a way to simplify applications that had to wait for more than one different thing:  An app with ten threads waiting each waiting for one kind of event/input was often easier to understand than a single-threaded app with one big event-processing loop that dispatched to ten different handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not bad to have waiting threads in general, it is common practice and often the nicest solution.

As the answer is pretty short, just a quick advice:
**If it is not necessary that your thread reacts immediately**, you might consider adding `Thread.yield` to your infinite waiting loop, depending on the system it is running on this can save some unnecessary CPU-usage. [See the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29)